# P2P web based automated response based on user query

Tags: chat, iot, messaging, p2p, peer

I would like to create a web based p2p application between two nodes. A website shows a list of nodes. When a user (say A) clicks on a node, it must setup a p2p chat like connection between the two.  It goes like this : once connection is established, node A can send a query message to B. Once B receives the query message, B must respond with the correct answer, (if A queries : RETRIEVE x.txt, B's response must be the contents of x.txt) I would like to be pointed into the right direction regarding the proper tech / protocols to be used. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to reach all the nodes, you need to collect their information so that when you click, you can connect to it.

Secondly, if you want to connect to these nodes, you need to do NAT traversal so that they can connect to each other.

Thirdly, you may want a reliable connection, so you need reliable UDP.

According these, you need the following protocols:

1. Creating a center controller like tracker to collect infomations
2. Creating NAT traversal, like nat-pmp and upnp, and it's better if you can build a ICE in the center controller
3. When click to some node, using udp to connect to it
4. If you want the connection reliable, you may also need to do reliable UDP, like QUIC, kcp or libutp.

Comment: What's more, you may need to find peers if you don't want to have a center controller, that is LSD and DHT protocol.